# FluxMonitor submits the wrong value

Tags: chainlink

I've deployed a FLuxAggregator on Rinkeby testnet and trying now to communicate with it from a local node.

the job spec is:

```
{
"initiators": [
    {
        "type": "fluxmonitor",
        "params": {
            "address": "0x56a1CB8672C6Deb270C764B0Dd5142B7726751F1",
            "requestData": {
                "data": {
                    "from": "ETH",
                    "to": "USD"
                }
            },
            "feeds": [
                {
                    "bridge": "coinapi_cl_ea"
                },
                {
                    "bridge": "coingecko_cl_ea"
                }
            ],
            "threshold": 1,
            "absoluteThreshold": 1,
            "precision": 8,
            "pollTimer": {
                "period": "5m0s"
            },
            "idleTimer": {
                "duration": "1h0m0s"
            }
        }
    }
],
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "NoOp"
    },
    {
      "type": "ethtx"
    }
]}
```

I can see in "noOp" that I have a good value "1900 USD/ETHER". However, "submit" transactions revert.
When checking a transaction on Rinkeby:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x9de2c4e12c76e93f2c99ebe471cbcc1d0b9e3080ba34d5467242cf0f45074690 , I'm noticing that the fluxmonitor submits a wrong value . In fact it submits "6432"
Could you please help me out? maybe my job spec is wrong

Comment: Are both external adapters returning 1900?

Comment: Hi @PatrickCollins . Not really, this is average value of the values returned by my 2 adapters.  i managed to get a working job, had to add other adapters to my job:
{
          "type": "multiply",
          "params": {
            "times": "100000000"
          }
        },
        {
            "type": "ethuint256"
        },
        {
            "type": "ethtx"
        }

Still confusing though.. Thought that FluxMonitor initiator will handle that as it requires a "precision" parameter.